# tabalyout loses its animation(smooth scroll)

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a TabLayout which is connected to a ViewPager. each page of my ViewPager is a Fragment. at the first, when I tap on any tab, it smoothly scrolls to that tab and its related page gets visible but after doing the same work for all tabs, when I tap again on one of tabs, it jumps to that position and I can not see any animation(smooth scroll), however I still can swipe smoothly between the pages. any Idea what is making the problem and how to solve that? thanx

UPDATE:
fragments:

```
    @Override
public void requestContentJsonUpdate() // it is called each time the related tab is selected to download data from server. however it happens only the first time
{
    if (!getIsLoaded())
    {
        requestParametricContentJsonUpdate();
    }

}
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_infinity, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_infinity_recycler_view);
    if (recyclerViewAdapter == null)
    {
        recyclerViewAdapter = new SpecificCategoryFragmentRecyclerAdapter
                (mContext, this, SupportsGridAndListArrangement.GRID_VIEW);
    }
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);
    generateStaggeredGridLayout();
    setUpRecyclerViewAnimation();

    addInfinityFeature();

    return view;
}
```

adapter:

```
public SpecificCategoryFragmentRecyclerAdapter(Context context, SpecificCategoryFragment fragment, int viewMode)
{
    super(context, viewMode);
    specificCategoryFragment = fragment;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)
{
    View view;
    if (i == TYPE_ITEM)
    {
        if (arrangeMode == SupportsGridAndListArrangement.GRID_VIEW)
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate
                    (R.layout.grid_advertisement_layout, null);
        }
        else
        {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate
                    (R.layout.list_advertisement_layout, null);
        }
        return new ItemHolder(view, mContext, arrangeMode);
    }
    else if (i == TYPE_HEADER)
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate
                (R.layout.caafe_fragment_header, null);
        return new HeaderHolder(view);
    }
    else
    {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate
                (R.layout.subcategory_item_row, null);
        return new SubcategoryHolder(view);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i)
{
    ((HomeActivity) mContext).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
         ...
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
   ...
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    if (jsonDatabase != null)
    {
        return jsonDatabase.getCount();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I'm sure you made a mistake in your code.

Comment: @NicolasSimon each fragment has a recyclerview which has a number(maybe alot) of cardviews. is it possible that it is because of memory issues?

Comment: Don't you think it'd be easier for us to help you if we were actually seeing your code?

Comment: @NicolasSimon updated ;)